# Joda DateTimeFormat list of timezones

Tags: calendar, jodatime

I just discover CET is not a valid timezone for Joda time:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER  = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");

DateTime.parse("25/11/2016 11:50:00.000 CET", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER)`     
  -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "25/11/2016 11:50:00.000 CET" is malformed at "CET"`

DateTime.parse("25/11/2016 11:50:00.000 PST", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER)`     
  -> OK
```

What is the official list of timezones? CET is a valid value for java.util.Calendar, but apparently not in Joda. The [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) doesn't say a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you cited also says:

> Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

Otherwise, if you use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` then you could use its method [appendTimeZoneName(Map<String,DateTimeZone>)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendTimeZoneName-java.util.Map-) with specifying a lookup-map. By default, this lookup-map is given by the helper method [DateTimeUtils.getDefaultTimeZoneNames()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getDefaultTimeZoneNames--) which only yields the English names of some US-located timezones:

```
•UT - UTC 
•UTC - UTC 
•GMT - UTC 
•EST - America/New_York 
•EDT - America/New_York 
•CST - America/Chicago 
•CDT - America/Chicago 
•MST - America/Denver 
•MDT - America/Denver 
•PST - America/Los_Angeles 
•PDT - America/Los_Angeles
```

**Solution:** Define your own lookup-map containing the string "CET", or use a better library for timezone-name-parsing (for example: Java-8 aka java.time-package does it better).

Comment: What about the rest of the world?

Comment: @stef The rest of the world (i.e. other time zone name abbreviations) is not supported by Joda-Time in parsing, for example CET... unless you are willing to set up your own name-zone-lookup-map (as described by given link in the answer). Here other time libraries have always been better, even `SimpleDateFormat` (although I don't recommend it for many other reasons). Keep also in mind that Joda-Time is now in maintenance mode so no big enhancements can be expected in the future and hence no fix of this limitation.